# VS code Version: 1.70.2 autosave not working on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I have recently downloaded VS code on my Mac, the ARM64 version and even if I toggle the autosave in the files the files are not getting saved, I did set afterdelay in the Prefrences>Setting>autosave but still files are not being saved automatically whenever I exit the file VScode asks me to save the file, so what am I doing wrong? I think only I am facing this problem so any kind of help is appreciated, and are there any extensions for this if I can't figure out anything it would be nice to have a alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to close for update the vscode and now I can click the "Auto Save" from "File" menu as referred here: [code.visualstudio.com/docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20turn,off%20%2D%20to%20disable%20auto%20save.)

*I'm also using the M1 MAckbook Pro.